# Duplicated files copied in APK. Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin, datastore

I'm trying to send a file to my Datastore of google. When I try to run the application I take the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files
> >     copied in APK
> >     com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/sep_approx_spanish.txt
> >       File1:
> >     C:\Users\Javier.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.appengine\appengine-endpoints\1.9.28\bf2e8a74bd28e388b3487fc78a0c7adfa592fd5d\appengine-endpoints-1.9.28.jar
> >       File2:
> >     C:\Users\Javier.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.34\7c15c22fd362478e9758081d28e51590304d5ff4\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.34.jar

I tried exclude the file with

```html
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'sep_approx_spanish.txt'
    }
```

but it doesn't work. My Build.gradle is the next:

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.javier.wh"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'sep_approx_spanish.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.34'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.28'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.28'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.12'
}
```

Someone had the same problem? 
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Put below line in your app build.gradle inside android block

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'com/google/appengine/repackaged/org/apache/commons/codec/language/bm/sep_approx_spanish.txt'
 }
```